# How to work with multiple conditional deferred response in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two ajax calls, one of which is conditional i.e.

```
   var url1Response, url2Response;

   var def1 = $.ajax({
                    url: Url1,
                    success: function (response) {
                        url1Response= response;
                    }

                });

   var def2 = $.ajax({
                    url: Url2,
                    success: function (response) {
                        url2Response= response;
                    }
                });

   var defs = [];
   defs.push(def1);
   if (x == 1) // some condition
      defs.push(def2);

   $.when.apply($, defs).then(_self.callback, _self.failureCallback);

   _self.callback = function (response) {

   };
   _self.failureCallback = function (response) {

   };
```

When both the def are being executed I am not able to see both the responses in callback input parameter. I am able to see only the url1Response.

Could someone please help me how to handled such conditional deferred statement response i.e. only1 ajax executed, both executed, both executed but one failed etc.?

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you use `$.when.apply($, defs)`, each response will be send to `then` as a different parameter. So, you can take it as:

```
_self.callback = function (response1, response2) {
};
```

or even you can use spread syntax:

```
_self.callback = function (...responses) {
    // response is a array with all responses
};
```